# How do I remove the arrow for a particular group (row) in an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

By default every group has a downward arrow that indicates to the user that the item can be expanded.  However, I have one group that has no children; thus, I would like the arrow to not show on this item.

Comment: Are you using your own custom adapter? Or a standard one defined in the SDK?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> **public void setGroupIndicator (Drawable groupIndicator)** 
> Sets the indicator to be drawn next to a group.
>
> **Parameters**
> *groupIndicator* The drawable to be used as an indicator. If the group is empty, the state [`state_empty`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_empty) will be set. If the group is expanded, the state [`state_expanded`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_expanded) will be set.

So hypothetically, this should already do the right thing... But, if you are using your own custom `ExpandableListAdapter`, with TextViews for example, you can use the following code:

```
// in your main file where the List is defined:
mExpandableList.setGroupIndicator(null); // this will remove the indicator
```

Then in your custom adapter you could do the following:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v;
    ...
    // code to retrieve convertView or inflate new one and assign to v
    ...

    TextView tv = ((TextView) v);
    int iconId;  // assume we have an icon we want to have on the left of each group
    int expandableGroupResId;

    if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) > 0) {
        if (isExpanded) expandableGroupResId = R.drawable.expander_ic_maximized;
        else expandableGroupResId = R.drawable.expander_ic_minimized;
    }
    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconId, 0, expandableGroupResId, 0);
}
```